# Time series explorer

Tags: data-visualization, data-analysis

Is there software which allows for the exploration of a multi-dimensional time-series?

## Example exploration

For this use case, assume I am monitoring traffic flow throughout a city. I want to see various traffic patterns and when they've happened before.

For example, given the following data series of cars/minute at the intersection of King & Union:

[image: traffic at King & Union]

I want to select a specific period of time:

[image: selection of time-series subset]

And I would get a list of previous times where this pattern occurred. Such as:

```
2016-02-01 9:00:00-10:00:00
2016-05-12 8:00:00-9:00:00
```

I can then translate the date-list and make more plots!

Additionally, I would like to be able to find where a pattern has previously occurred:

- At a different location (i.e. Queen and Bathurst)
- In a different metric (i.e. total number of red cars in the last hour, which would require some data manipulation to translate between the domains)
- Using multiple metrics (i.e. traffic at King & Union, as well as Queen & Bathurst between 1pm to 2pm, giving at 2-dimensional time-series)

## Previously investigated products

### [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)

Doesn't seem to have easy GUI-based querying enabled.

### [Azure Time-Series Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-explorer)

Has a selectable GUI, but doesn't seem to satisfy the use cases illustrated above.

Comment: Did you ever find anything for this?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica This definitely does not exist and had to be made from scratch in my previous company. In terms of time-series pattern matching, this is an EXTREMELY unsolved problem. You can do Dynamic Time Warping, Machine-Learning Clustering or simple Euclidean Distance.

Comment: Sounds like a start-up to me :-)  Thanks for letting us know